# How to get current IANA Timezone Database version in Golang?

Tags: go, time, timezone, iana

I need to store datetime records with [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) database current version used (2022g for example). How could I get it with Go?

I tried to search this on standard "time" package, but it seems that there isn't any functionality for this. I am expecting that there is some function that can return IANA tzdb version as a string.

UPDATE 1 according to comments below I need to clarify the problem:

The main problem is I want to store some FUTURE events. The event object has several fields:

1. Local dateTime
2. Timezone
3. UTC datetime

To keep my data up to date with IANA database (timezone, daylight saving time may change) I need to store current version of tzdb version. That will help me to write correct data migration of my events when new version of tzdb was released. So I need to add one more field with version of current tzdb that had been used to populate the time.

And I am trying to figure out how can I get the current version of my tzdb that Go application is using right now to store that version.

Also I am opened to alternative solutions of storing time records with  extra accuracy of long-lived future events.

Update 2: This events are bounded to exact location.

Comment: I do not understand the exact problem: looks like the question contains multiple questions in one. Please be more specific. Are you about figuring out what version of a timezone database a running Go program uses?

Comment: Maybe those packages can help you. You could regenerate timezones/abbrvs using the tools provided. https://github.com/tkuchiki/go-timezone https://github.com/tkuchiki/timezones

Comment: @kostix exactly
I need to get current version of timezone database a running Go program uses

Comment: Then there's no possibility to do that using the standard library. Another problem you might be unaware of is that this DB (called "Olsen's database") is only used on Linux- and *BSD based systems (and may be on macosx, I dunno) but not on Windows, which has a system-provided API to query TZ information. I mean, querying such a version has no sense in a cross-platform code.

Comment: You may look at <https://go.dev/src/time/> and see that getting timezone info is really platform-dependent. Having said that, you could replicate the heuristics from `src/time/zoneinfo_unix.go`. The `tzdata.zi` file in the directory with the TZ data has its version listed in its first line. I know this stinks, but at the same time I do not think something will drastically change midterm in the way the Olsen's DB is handled on popular platforms.

Comment: Well, and while we're at it I should mention that maybe you're trying to solve a wrong problem: being concerned withthe TZDB version is a system's (or container's) task and should probably dealt with on another layer in your system.

Comment: @NikitaAlkhovik - Perhaps if you elaborated about *why* you need to do this, we might be able to offer an alternative approach.

Comment: I updated the question. One solution that could help me the solve entire problem is just store the current version of tzdb as a constant. But it seems that I cannot control what version of tzdb my Go application is using right now.

Comment: Also as @kostix mentioned, one more solution is trying to parse current version from tzdata.zi file. This could work for me I suppose

Comment: Nikita, actually, you can: if you read that `zoneinfo_unix.go` file, you'll notice that the `TZ` environment variable can actually contain the full path to a tzdata directory besides the timezone itself. So basically you could ship your very own copy of the db along with your app. I'm not sure it will work as an embedded resource though. Another possible approach is to maintain a patch atop of the Go sources which would force the runtime to use a specific tzdata version, possibly bundled.

Comment: Anyway, I'm with @MattJohnson-Pint: your question looks very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so it would be cool if you would describe the _root_ problem you're trying to solve instead of problems with your attempted ideas/solutions at solving _that_ problem ;-)

Comment: Ah, OK, the update to your question sheds way more light to the problem at hand, thanks. Well, do you understand that the timezone information only has impact on _timestamp *presentation*_ and not on the time instants themselves? I mean, say, when I'll post this comment my wall clock will be showing time using UTC+4 and someone might read it while their wall clock is showing time using UTC-8, but _both these clocks show the exactly same moment of time._

Comment: So if you store your events "the sensible way"—say, using so-called [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), or any such approach (say, Microsoft uses [this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times) to store file creation/modification times)—the problem becomes nonexistent: when you need to display or interpret time, you use whatever TZDB your program currently uses, and keeping it up-to-date is the user's/sysadmin's/devop's problam, and this in no way affects what you _store._

Comment: With Go, it's easy to manipulate Unix times up to nanosecond precision, which will have you covered up until the year 2100-something, which, I would say, is pretty OK: by this time we will either have been perished in a nuclear meltdown or have switched to integers larger than 64-bit, so you'll be able to upgrade. If this is too precise, you can use millisecon precision.

Comment: @kostix there is some misunderstanding over here. I don't need time accuracy in second or nanosecond. I just wanna be sure that timezones and daylight savings are up to date with my data stored. For example, I am store some time in timezone Asia/Tokyo. I need to be sure that this timezone will exist and their DST wasn't changed with next release ([changelog](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdb/NEWS) shows that some countries may or may not respect DST in the future. Some timezones can be renamed)

Comment: That's not what I wanted to explain. You mention "events". Events, to me, sound like moments in time (in the past or in the future). Moments in time do not in any way depend on purely policital stuff which timesones and DST are. The flow of time is universal across planet Earth. Again, the moment I post this comment on SO is the same for me and for you even though we're likely to reside in different timezones, and this moment would be _rendered_ likely differently by our computers, but this does not change the fact is the same moment of time. So, if you pick a suitable representation to store…

Comment: …such time instants, the problem of timezones goes away completely. For example, the venerable "Unix time" is one of such representations: it's a number of seconds passed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and this number is the same for any given moment of time, no matter which timezone happens to be active for a program dealing with it.

Comment: @kostix Imagine the situation:
- You created an appointment to a doctor in Tokyo at 2024-01-13T03:02:36+09:00.
- The server converts this data to utc 2024-01-12T21:02:36 and store it as a timestamp.
For this two years Tokyo decide to addDST 1 extra hour.
- Then when you want to get you appointment from the server it converts a utc stored data to Tokyo timezone.
- You just arrived at the meeting earlier in 1 hour.

This is the problem that I am trying to solve. Hope it helps to understand

Comment: I understand the problem but I fail to get your fixation because every other existing program has the same problem but are OK with it. I mean, if I run a desktop computer (I do) I'm responsible for keeping it updated (updates include the tzdb updates as well). If I maintain "server-side" software (folks at my $dayjob do) they are responsible for keeping their host systems and their container images (or running containers) updated, and I am well aware that they have this problem solved. If, say, my laptop will stop receiving tzdb updates, _all_ software on it will be affected, not only yours.

Comment: Update the tzdb on the devices do not updates the actual data. This data just converts to updated representation and this representation is incorrect because data was stored on stale version of the tzdb. So I need to adapt the data according the fresh release of tzdb.

Comment: OK, I honestly tried. Have fun, cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

The discussion thread in the comment is pretty long, but I'll attempt to answer and address some of the concerns.  (I won't address the question in the title, as I believe that is not straightforward in Go.)

- Indeed, future scheduling of events should be in terms of the time zone where the event takes place - which is usually not UTC.
- Time zone identifiers will never be removed or renamed (with rare exception anyway).  Once introduced, the identifier will either maintained as a `Zone` or as a `Link` in the TZDB indefinitely.  Thus, you don't need to check that the time zone still exists.  (Windows time zone IDs are also like this.)
- DST is only one aspect of picking the correct offset.  The standard time may have changed as well.  However, all of that is encapsulated in the tzdb itself.  You shouldn't need to concern yourself about which version of the tzdb was in effect when you created the event.

The general approach to this issue in most cases is:

- Store the scheduled local date, time, and time zone ID of the event (local with regard to the time zone of the event).

  Example: `2030-12-31T00:00:00[America/New_York]`
- At the time you create the event, also calculate a UTC value (or equivalent `DateTimeOffset` value) and store that in a separate field - so you know exactly when to fire the event:

  Example: `2030-12-31T05:00:00Z` (or `2030-12-31T00:00:00-05:00`)
- Periodically check that your UTC equivalent is correct.  This can be in a daily maintenance task, or on application startup, or just before the event (perhaps also an hour before the event), or all of these.

  The offset will only be different than projected if the time zone data changed on the device to give it a new offset.  For example, let's hypothetically say the lawmakers in the USA succeed at making DST permanent sometime before this event takes place.  Then the equivalent UTC time for the same event would now be `2030-12-31T04:00:00Z` (or `2030-12-31T00:00:00-04:00`).

  In such cases, update the UTC time of the event if it has changed, but the original local time of the event usually should not be modified.  Human beings tend to schedule things in terms of local time, not in terms of their UTC equivalents.

The only advantage knowing the TZDB version would give you, is you could do that last step less often - only when knowing the data has changed.  I see that as an optimization though - it's not usually required.

- Without such legal changes to time zone definitions, the mere start/stop of DST as scheduled is not a reason to worry about this.  That is already accounted for by using the TZDB in the first place.

  - If the event is *recurring* (say a 10:00 AM daily meeting), each occurrence might have a different offset, but the local time will be consistent and the TZDB doesn't need to be updated to calculate it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You fully understand what problem I am trying to solve.
As you've mentioned on step 3 there are some alternative solutions to check if UTC equivalent is correct.  I don't want to perform the database queries so often to check values so for my needs it seems like the only valid solution for me is to check UTC value before firing the event with latest version of TZDB available.In this case I really do not need to know the exact version - I'll just use the latest one. However, it wouldn't save me when timezone was deleted from tzdb. In that case I'll use the datamigration.